# Integrating TypeGraphQL and file uploads with Apollo Server v4

Tags: graphql, apollo-server, typegraphql

The new apollo server v4 is out and I am having problem integrating  `TypeGraphQL` with `@apollo/server`. I somehow integrated myself but getting this error. It says `TypeGraphQL` have `UnmetGraphQLPeerDependencyError` .

```
UnmetGraphQLPeerDependencyError: Looks like you use an incorrect version of the 'graphql' package: "16.6.0". Please ensure that you have installed a version that meets TypeGraphQL's requirement: "^15.3.0".
```

I tried changing the `GraphQL` version to `^15.3.0`  in `package.json` but now `@apollo/server` has `UnmetGraphQLPeerDependencyError`

```
"dependencies": {
    "@apollo/server": "^4.3.0",
    "@graphql-tools/schema": "^9.0.12",
    "body-parser": "^1.20.1",
    "class-validator": "^0.14.0",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "fastify": "^4.10.2",
    "graphql": "^15.3.0",
    "graphql-tag": "^2.12.6",
    "mercurius": "^11.4.0",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.13",
    "type-graphql": "^1.1.1"
  }
```

I have a general idea of setting up file uploads with `graphqlUploadExpress`. Is there anything different in typegraphql?

Comment: Try upgrading `type-graphql` to `next`: `npm install --save type-graphql@next`. See [this](https://github.com/MichalLytek/type-graphql/issues/1100) for more information.

Answer (score 2):

Installing the `version:2` of `type-graphql` solved my issue:

```bash
yarn add type-graphql@next
```

Using `npm`

```bash
npm i type-graphql@next
```